# Trying to display last month data from SQL database - where clause

Tags: sql, database, maximo

I am using a where clause to run a query in a system.

The below where clause works when I want to look at data changed in the last 7 days. But I now need to find data changed last month. I do not want last 30 days as I need to have this run each month.

changedate >= dateadd(day,-7,getdate())

Please help? By "Last Month" I mean the previous months data. For example if the report is run on the 5th of July, the data displays results from 1st June - 30th June.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  What do you mean by "last month"?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want:

```
changedate >= dateadd(month, -1, getdate())
```

EDIT:

If you want the previous complete month:

```
changedate < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) and
changedate >= dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
```

Or, if you don't care about optimizing the query (because this prevents the use of partitions):

```
datediff(month, changedate, getdate()) = 1
```

Comment: This gives me the last 30 days from the current date. It doesn't give me the previous month data. For example the report will run on the 4th of July, I need the data to display for 1st June - 30th June.

Comment: @SQL_Question . . . That was the clarification I was looking for.  I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
changedate  between DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2)) and EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)
```

or

```
month(changedate) = month(getdate()) -1 
and year(changedate) = year(getdate())
```